# How do I detect bugs, leaks and anomalies in the GPU? (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-leaks

I'm coding a game engine and doing lots of tests, and (I think) I'm following all the "best practices" I could find.

Double, triple checked the code to make sure resources are being properly released and deleted, and in the code there's no leaks.

But I think there must be something wrong going on, as I've had my first blue screen of death in various years these days. I've also noticed the computer seeming... sluggish at some times (unusual behaviour) when it's not supposed to.

Since I've been checking (and will continue to do so) my code, I can only guess it must be something GPU related.

Is there a way for me to check the memory being used/allocated during a program, sorta like a debug and/or something similar to check for errors in the GPU?

I've searched around a bit and found about CUDA but it seems to be nVidia only (and I'm using a Radeon), so I'm asking for either possibilities or general tools (if they exist at all!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only work with OpenCL, but I think [AMD's CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/) is what you want. It reports info about GPU load, memory, etc.